# Volume of geodesic ball in constant sectional curvature manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry

$M$ is n-dimensional Riemannian manifold, and  has constant sectional curvature $K_0$. When $r>0$ is small enough, denote
$$
B(p,r) = \exp_p(B(r))
$$
where $B(r)\subset T_pM$ is a ball of radius $r$ and centered on the origin. I know the volume of $B(p,r)$ has form
$$
Vol(B(p,r)) = C(K_0) r^n
$$
where $C(K_0)$ is constant depending on $K_0$.  This morning, I try to prove it. But fail. And seemly, in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, there is not an example about this from the point of   volume form. Therefore, I want to know how to calculate it or where I can find the calculation. Thanks.

Comment: The formula you've written is incorrect; The volume is only proportional to $r^n$ when $K_0=0$. As for computing the correct form, are you familiar with the [Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field)?

Comment: @Kajelad  I am familiar with Jacobi equation (or Jacobi field).